# How should I set the OAuth redirect_uri for the LinkedIn API on multiple subdomains (different instances of the same app) without violating the TOS?

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I know this isn't exactly a how-to question, but Linked-In Support directed me to StackOverflow when I asked them this question, and I cannot find the answer anywhere after googling/searching the forums:

Per the LinkedIn APIs Terms of Use (https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use), section E.1, second bullet point:

> Don’t try to exceed or circumvent your limitations on calls and use.
>   This includes creating multiple Applications for identical, or largely
>   similar, usage (e.g., having one Application per customer). If we
>   believe that you have exceeded or circumvented our limitations, or if
>   you have tried to, we may temporarily suspend or permanently block
>   your access to the APIs, disable your developer account, or both.

It sounds like I'm not allowed to create multiple instances of an application. However, the nature of my software is that each of my clients gets a subdomain and runs an instance of my app on a server particular to that client. Each client thus needs their own OAuth redirect_uri, and the only solution that I can think of is to create an application for each of my clients (which are organizations and not individual users).

Does this practice violate the TOS, and if so, what's a viable alternative?

If this practice is allowed, what is the maximum number of applications (and API keys) I can create?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register a single client/app but add multiple RedirectURI's for that instance, one for each customer/domain. This is allowed per LinkedIn documentation by adding multiple URLs in the OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs text area, separated by a comma:

> OAuth 2.0 Redirect URLs: Comma separated list of absolute URLs allowed
>   for OAuth 2.0 redirections.

Comment: Now that I read the answer, it seems so obvious.  I had wondered how LinkedIn knew which URL to redirect to, but for some reason the brain didn't make the connection that request_uri is sent along with the request.  Thanks!

Comment: @Hans Z. What happens when we have numerous sub-domains it's a trouble to add each new domain manually into Redirect URL's list.